# Gimp adjust brightness not applying to image

Tags: gimp

I have a strange behavior, I'm using GIMP 2.10.8 on Ubuntu 18.10, Sorry I'm newbie.

1. I copied one image and pasted to new layer.
2. I changed the color using Colors -> Colorize
3. I wanted to increase brightness so did the following Colors -> Brightness/Contrast increased Contrast to 70+
4. Preview working fine, when I hit OK, it's not applying.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I've tried to repeat what you did, but it works as expected, and I can't replicate the problem you are experiencing.  Can you check your image mode is in RGB mode, and not Indexed mode. It's  the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

You can have such a problem if your layer has a partial opacity (ie, Alpha<100% on all pixels). When you apply Brightness-Contrast, you are viewing a fully opaque preview, but when you commit, alpha is restored and this dims the effect.

This could be a bug in Gimp 2.10

Comment: I agree. That seems to be the problem. I tried again to replicate the issue demonstrated by the OP, but this time I used an image with semi-transparent pixels.  It would seem to be a preview issue/bug more than anything else, the filter still works. It just looks different when you commit.